# How to add new item to the Windows 10 "All Apps" section

Tags: windows, windows-10, start-menu

I want to add a new item (in this particular case a shortcut to Putty SSH client) to my Windows 10's All Apps section.

I have already found out that I can "Pin to Start" any item, however, this will only create a new tile on the right side of the Start Menu and won't add any new item to All Apps. Thus, pressing  <kbd>Win</kbd> and typing "putty" won't return any result.

Creating a new shortcut and adding it to `shell:start menu` has the same effect as pinning to Start, so it's not a solution.

*Note:* [this](https://superuser.com/questions/948088/how-to-add-exe-to-start-menu-in-windows-10) question might look the same, but the accepted answer doesn't apply to my requirements as I need the item to be searchable, and not only a new tile.

*Note 2:* I can confirm that after waiting several hours for Windows to reindex its index I manually rebuilt the whole index, but putty still can't be found neither in search results nor in "All Apps" list.

Comment: Answer to that question seems to be correct. The item will be a regular Start item, just like any other, and thus will be searchable. You may have to wait a few minutes for Windows to index it.

Comment: I have added this shortcut hours ago. Since then I had a restart, but still no cigar. Indexing option says "Indexing complete"

Comment: I had this problem too and eventually discovered that "Pin to Start" breaks Search for that item, even after un-pinning it, adding a shortcut manually and re-building the index. The fix is to unpin the shortcut, *rename the app directory*, create a shortcut manually and then revert the name change. [Writeup here](http://blog.mgiuffrida.com/2017/01/28/why-you-cant-find-shortcut-start-menu.html). Then it shows in All Apps and can be searched for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is automatically added when you install new applications. To add manually put folders here

> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\

You can also try this location:

> C:\Users\ **YOUR_ID**\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\

Comment: Thanks! Creating a new folder inside Programs finally did the trick.

Comment: This does not work for me

Comment: Neither does it for me...

Comment: After adding a shortcut to this path, nothing came up in the search. But after clicking the `All apps` button, and seeing it was there under `Recently added` in the top - and also under its respective letter - it seemed to index it, because it then turned up in searches.

Comment: First one did the job for me. Thanks  a lot.