# Easy way to add shortcut to windows 10 start menu

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I used to launch apps by pressing Win button and typing the name of app i need. I want to add shortcut for portable app (i.e. PuTTY) to start menu Programs folder. In Windows 7 i would just drag and drop shortcut to "All Programs" or any of it's subfolder. This does not work for Windows 10, such drag'n'drop action in not availible. The only drag and drop action availible is for start menu button itself, where "Pin to Start menu" text hint displayed, before i drop shortcut on it. But this action does not add the shortcut to menu.

Ofcourse i can manually add something to: `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` but i hope there is more easy way to do what i want.

Comment: Create a shortcut to `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` and drag and drop what you want a shortcut to into that? It's just a different location to drag and drop to that way?

Comment: Related and/or possible duplicates: [How do I add a new program to the Start Menu?](http://superuser.com/q/954372/169501), [How to add exe to start menu in Windows 10?](http://superuser.com/q/948088/169501)

Answer (score 2):

Search for the program in the Search Bar. Right click it, and then select "Pin to Start". It will now be in the start menu.

Comment: When I search, it doesn't come up. It's as if the search doesn't cover Program Files