# How can I add an EXE to windows 10 All App list (without pinning to start menu)

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I want to add an EXE which is not installed to the All App list in Windows 10, in the All Apps section.

I tried this: [How to add exe to start menu in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/948088/how-to-add-exe-to-start-menu-in-windows-10)

However, that seems to have pinned it to my start menu. I don't want it pinned, just listed when I open All Apps and showing up when I search for the name.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Copy and paste the shortcut of the exe in the start menu.

Either create a shortcut and copy and paste it there or directly copy the .exe into the start menu.

This will allow you to place an program that is not in the all apps list.

All apps located there are shortcuts.

**Edit.**

Try this.

Create a new folder in your program folder.

**%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs**

Then Create a folder. And name it.

Now Create a shorcut of your **.exe** and place it in the folder.

This should add it to your app list like you want.

**Note:**
*The app list will not update unless you put the shortcut in after you create the folder.*

Comment: I want to add it to the All App List, not the start menu (I've edited the question)

Comment: updated the answer.

Comment: Nope, tried that, still only creates a pinned item in the Start menu

Comment: Strange that something as simple as putting a shortcut in an App List is so difficult... do you think there is a place to "register" the program in windows or something?

Comment: I will have to play with it when i get off work all of our enterprise systems run windows 7 or linux here. I did see an interesting post which may be the answer let me see if I can find it.

Comment: Have a look [Here](http://www.ghacks.net/2014/10/20/how-to-move-or-remove-apps-in-all-apps-in-the-windows-10-start-menu/) and see if this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Add `exe` shortcut to to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\` or to `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`

Comment: This still pins it to the start menu, when I unpin it, the shortcut is gone as well

Comment: add a folder then add shortcut ?